# Edit Site Header Area Text

Tags: wordpress

If you have a look at flexicanedistributors.co.za you will a cellphone number and opening times in the top left in the header. I have tried to edit it as i would like as:

Cell: 34334

Email:343434

Opening Hours: 3dad

I have attempted to edit the themes code but have come up short.

I have attempted to edit the themes files in the editor but I seem to break some of the code.

Comment: This question doesn't make enough sense. Please give code examples of what you have tried to do, what you expected to happen, and what actually happened so that someone can easier help you figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

According to the source code of your website you are currently running a WP theme called Ironfit _ and there is also reference and links to a 'customizer' file _

This means that you need to access the header of your website by logging in to the site via WPAdmin and finding the 'Customizer' option on the Wordpress dashboard _ Customizer may be labelled slightly differently_ but if you can access the Customizer area of the main menu then you should be able to see the phone number etc that you are trying to change

Comment: I have checked that. But it simply lets me change just the wording for the Open: section and the cell number , it does not allow me to change the layout. I know there is a way to change the theme code but I am not that versed in it.

Comment: There are 3 tiers to Wordpress _ Tier 1 is what viewers see but have no access _ Tier 2 allows site owner access to WP dashboard & Customizer to change contact details_ make new posts_ change menu items & some aspects of the theme _ Tier 3 is where the actual theme is created & altered with code _ To make these changes successfully you would need to be well-versed in at least 4 languages_ including HTML CSS Javascript and PHP _ **If these comments have answered your question then you should consider deleting the question because Stack Overflow is really for questions about actual coding**